# how to use a conditional filter on a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2x df's with data in them, and the index are dates

```
dfcarry = {'EUR3m3m': [1.5, 0.6, 1.7, 1.5, -1.2],
           'EUR6m3m': [2.0, 1.2, 1.3, 0.6, -1.7],
         'EUR6m3m3m': [1.3, 1.0, -1.4, 0.5, np.nan]}
dfcarry = pd.DataFrame(dfcarry, index=['26-09-2016','25-09-2016','24-09-2016','23-09-2016'])
```

and

```
dfflags = {'EUR3m3m': [1, 0, 1, 1, -1],
           'EUR6m3m': [1, 1, 1, 0, -1],
         'EUR6m3m3m': [1, 1, -1, 0, 0]}
dfflags = pd.DataFrame(dfflags, index=['26-09-2016','25-09-2016','24-09-2016','23-09-2016'])
```

Now, what I want to do is to limit the abs value of the sum of the numbers to 1, so for any given date, I can not have more than 2 flags in the same direction, i.e. a 1 cancels out a -1:

```
if abs(sum(dfflags['26-09-2016'])) > 1:
     then convert one of the flags to zero
```

then, the integer I want to get rid of is the value where the corresponding abs(carry) number is the least. If we have too many 1's, we get rid of the 1 where the carry number is least. If we have too many -1's in flags, we get rid of a -1 where the carry number is highest (least -ve)

In my carry df, i have some nans (on purpose).

How do I do this?

So to be clear, for the first date, `'26-09-2016'`, the expected output is to keep a 1 at `EUR6m3m`, because I keep the 1 corresponsding to the highest absolute values of carry ( so I keep carry=2.0, and get rid of carry=1.5 and 1.3).

expected output overall is

```
dfflags = {'EUR3m3m': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         'EUR6m3m':   [1, 1, 1, 0, -1],
         'EUR6m3m3m': [0, 0, -1, 0, 0]}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to fix your sample data , index len